# Windows Azure creating virtual directory to local storage

Tags: azure, directory, virtual, storage, local

I need a help with creating virtual directory pointing to local storage in Windows Azure (production environment). I can set up a virtual directory manually but it is being erased every time Azure is restarted. The clue is to create the virtual directory via config file when I upload a package of my project on Azure. The question is how to create such directory so that it is pointing to local storage.

Thx in advance for any suggestions.

Best Regards,

Darek

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you create the virtual directory by interacting with IIS in the WebRole's OnStart method:

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // Connect to the IIS site.
        using (var manager = new Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager())
        { 
                var localResourcePath = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("MyResource").RootPath;

            // Add to the root application.
            var rootSite = manager.Sites[RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id + "_Web"];
            var rootApplication = rootSite.Applications["/"];
                rootApplication.VirtualDirectories.Add("/myVdir", localResourcePath);

                // Save
            manager.CommitChanges();
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

If I'm right you'll need to set the execution context to **elevated** for this to work. You can do this in the ServiceDefintion.csdef:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="MyProject" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2012-05.1.7">
  <WebRole name="MyRole" vmsize="Small" enableNativeCodeExecution="true">
    <Runtime executionContext="elevated" />
    ...
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

**Note:** You'll need to reference **Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll** (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv)