# Get publication path when publishing Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-directory

I followed this thread to create a virtual directory in Azure Cloud Services: [Windows Azure creating virtual directory to local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187877/windows-azure-creating-virtual-directory-to-local-storage).

It works fine but I'm not able to get "localResourcePath" with the path Azure located the files.

Where do I have to set "MyResource"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"MyResource" is a LocalStorage resource you define in your CSDEF file - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee758711.aspx.

You would add the following to your CSDEF (changing sizeInMB as appropriate):

> ```
> <LocalResources>
>   <LocalStorage name="MyResource" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" sizeInMB="1000" />
> </LocalResources>
> ```